# Why are some System Preferences icons "Generic" in macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, system-settings

Something weird is going on with the Icons for a few of the built-in System Preference prefPanes in macOS 10.15.x Catalina. For example, "Bluetooth" and "Internet Accounts". When I search Spotlight for these, the proper icon is displayed:

[image: bt-spotlight]

But, in Finder or [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) only a generic icon is shown:

[image: bt-alfred]

another example is **Internet Accounts**:

[image: internet-spotlight]

vs

[image: internet-alfred]

I notice even in Finder, the generic icons are shown:

[image: generic-Finder]

Only Spotlight and the System Preferences.app itself seem capable of showing the proper icon. I opened the Contents folder of the prefPane bundle to investigate. It seems like **Info.plist** contained within specifies icons via keys such as `NSPrefPaneIconFile` and `CFBundleIconFile` but even in that case, the file referenced doesn't seem to exist on the filesystem anywhere that I can find.

E.g. for Bluetooth, `NSPrefPaneIconFile = "BluetoothAqua.png"` — but that file doesn't exist. Similarly, Internet Accounts specifies `InternetAccountsIcons.icns` and `InternetAccountsIcon40.png` as icons, but these are nowhere to be found:

[image: terminal-no-results]

Does anyone know what's going on here, or where the icon resources are being loaded from?

**edit:** Found some additional info about this. The icons for these prefPanes are being sourced from a compressed `Assets.car` (CoreUI Archive) within the bundle. Here are some related links I found:

[Reverse engineering the .car file format](https://blog.timac.org/2018/1018-reverse-engineering-the-car-file-format/)

[insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer: open .car files and browse/extract their images](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer)

[Analysing Assets.car file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios)

[steventroughtonsmith/cartool: Export images from CoreUI archives](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool)

Comment: Just found this today and decided to try to help. Did you try to restart and use different user accounts and see if that would fix anything?

Answer (score 1):

The icons are present: they're just not being picked up by the Finder. That could be a caching problem (of the Finder's).

In the 10 months since this question was asked, it's possible that a system update may have fixed it (by clearing caches as part of the installation, rather than any pro-active fixing).